# I am having a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Python app with Heroku and I have now run into an internal server error. I am aware there are a lot of similar subjects posted, but since I am new to this I sadly fail to understand how to apply it to this specific instance..

Here is the error message from my Heroku logs I think is most relevant:

```
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485486+00:00 app[web.1]: message = from_number + ": " + body
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485487+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

and this is the code I am using:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import twilio.twiml
import pika, os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():

    from_number = request.values.get('From', None)
    body = request.values.get('Body', None)

    url_str = os.environ.get('CLOUDAMQP_URL','amqp://mysecretURL')
    url = urlparse(url_str)

    params = pika.ConnectionParameters(host=url.hostname, virtual_host=url.path[1:],
        credentials=pika.PlainCredentials(url.username, url.password))

    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='texts')

    message = from_number + ": " + body

    channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='texts', body=message)
    connection.close()

    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    resp.message("We're so happy! We got your message and it's currently printing. Tx, Elise T")
    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this is the rest of my logs if it happens to be interesting:

```
2020-06-22T11:38:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user e@gmail.com
2020-06-22T11:39:28.157969+00:00 app[api]: Release v52 created by user e@gmail.com
2020-06-22T11:39:28.157969+00:00 app[api]: Deploy dc80c553 by user e@gmail.com
2020-06-22T11:39:29.416229+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-06-22T11:39:29.455422+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-06-22T11:39:31.052359+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-06-22T11:39:31.097123+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-22 11:39:31 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-06-22T11:39:31.097912+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-22 11:39:31 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-06-22T11:39:31.119047+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-22 11:39:31 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2020-06-22T11:39:31.245715+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-22 11:39:31 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-06-22T11:39:31.373959+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-06-22T11:39:34.652160+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn --chdir daydreams-sms run:app`
2020-06-22T11:39:37.115252+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-22 11:39:37 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-06-22T11:39:37.115753+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-22 11:39:37 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:37823 (4)
2020-06-22T11:39:37.115849+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-22 11:39:37 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-06-22T11:39:37.122798+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-22 11:39:37 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-06-22T11:39:37.173703+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-22 11:39:37 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-06-22T11:39:37.499587+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-22T11:39:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485427+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-22 11:39:43,484] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485465+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485467+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485467+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485482+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485482+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485483+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485483+00:00 app[web.1]: reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485484+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485484+00:00 app[web.1]: raise value
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485484+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485485+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485485+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485485+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485486+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/daydreams-sms/run.py", line 24, in hello
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485486+00:00 app[web.1]: message = from_number + ": " + body
2020-06-22T11:39:43.485487+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, it is coming from the following line:

```
message = from_number + ": " + body
```

The values of `from_number` and `body` might be `None` because of the way they are defined:

```
from_number = request.values.get('From', None)
body = request.values.get('Body', None)
```

And python doesn't understand the `+` operator between `NoneType` and `str`.
You can convert `NoneType` to `str` like this:

```
message = str(from_number) + ": " + str(body)
```

OR

```
message = f"{from_number}: {body}"
```